# When extending ToolbarWindow in Vaadin, it throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

```
public class ViewPreviousClaims extends ToolbarWindow {

  public void initView() {
    setCaption("Previous Claim Details");
    this.setHeight("400px");
    this.setWidth("950px");
    this.setModal(false);
    this.setClosable(true);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.center();

    final ViewPreviousClaims currentInstance = this;

    VerticalLayout tools = new VerticalLayout();

      Button b = new Button(null, new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                currentInstance.setHeight("0px");
            }
        });
        b.setDescription("Minimize");
        b.setIcon(new ClassResource("minimize.png"));
        b.addStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_LINK);
        tools.addComponent(b);

        b = new Button(null, new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                if (currentInstance.getWidth() != 100) {
                    currentInstance.setSizeFull();
                } else {
                    currentInstance.setWidth("400px");
                    currentInstance.setHeight("300px");
                }
                currentInstance.center();
                event.getButton().focus();
            }
        });
        b.setDescription("Maximize");
        b.setIcon(new ClassResource("maximize.png"));
        b.addStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_LINK);
        tools.addComponent(b);

        this.setToolbar(tools);


 }
}
```

It throws

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.vaadin.cssinject.CSSInject: method <init>()V not found
```

Please see the error stack trace:

```
12:32:35,507 SEVERE [com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:9870-1) : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.vaadin.cssinject.CSSInject: method <init>()V not found
    at org.vaadin.toolbarwindow.ToolbarWindow.<init>(ToolbarWindow.java:22) [toolbarwindow-0.1.jar:0.1]
    at com.shaic.claim.registration.ViewPreviousClaims.<init>(ViewPreviousClaims.java:82) [classes:]
    at com.shaic.claim.ViewDetails.getViewPreviousClaimDetails(ViewDetails.java:3673) [classes:]
    at com.shaic.claim.ViewDetails$1.buttonClick(ViewDetails.java:945) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508) [vaadin-server-7.5.8.jar:7.5.8]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198) [vaadin-server-7.5.8.jar:7.5.8]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161) [vaadin-server-7.5.8.jar:7.5.8]
```

Comment: Did you add the CSSInject add-on in version 0.11 to your dependencies?

Comment: It looks like the class `CSSInject` is present but in a different version than required by `ToolbarWindow` add-on.

Comment: Looping in @SteffenHarbich as well: Hmm, just a wild thought but from the question tags it look like you're using Vaadin7. Looking at the [ToolbarWindow add-on page](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/toolbarwindow) it's clearly stated that  it requires *Vaadin6.3+* while **7 is not supported**. This would explain why it can't find a method, since the framework has suffered substantial changes between v 6 and 7.